# Is there a minimum number of instructions executed by thread during given time slot?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, execution, execution-time

Is there a minimum number of instruction guaranteed to be executed by a thread during any given time slot. The Wikipedia page for [Execution Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_model) says "The addition operation is an indivisible unit of work in many languages"

I would like to learn more about the execution model of POSIX Thread used with C/C++ and minimum number of indivisible instruction or statements guaranteed to be executed in a single time slot. Can someone give a pointer from where I can learn more on this. Thanks is advance

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, that you think an answer to your question would bring you closer to a solution? The only thing C++ standard guarantees is that "**[intro.multithread]/3** Implementations should ensure that all unblocked threads eventually make progress."

Comment: Not an answer to your question but: addition could be one instruction in some scenarios on some machines and more than one on others.  If you are adding two registers of the same size and putting the result back into a register of the same size then it will probably be one instruction and on a machine without instruction pipelining it will probably be one cycle.  But what if you need to read the values from memory - that almost always takes more than one cycle.  If the registers aren't all the same size the processor may have to do a read-modify-write which definitely isn't indivisible.

Comment: I've never considered this while writing multithreaded apps since it seems mostly irrelevant, but I suppose the answer is 'one machine instruction'.  It's not unreasonable for a thread to be set running on a core and then almost immediately interrupted and preempted by a higher-priority thread that has become ready on some I/O interrupt or inter-thread signaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no guarantees on the number of instructions per time. The way things work is more complicated than executing a set number of instructions anyway.

Executed instructions depends more on the processor architecture than the language. The "traditional" MIPS architecture taught in many introductory design courses would execute one instruction per clock cycle; a processor designed like this running at 1MHz would execute one million operations per second. Real-world processors use techniques such as pipelines, branch prediction, "hyper-threading", etc. and do not have a set number of operations per clock cycle.

Beyond that, real-world processors will generally function under an operating system with multi-tasking capabilities. This means that a thread can be interrupted by the kernel at unknown points, and not execute any code at all as other threads are given processor time. There are "real-time" operating systems that are designed to give more guarantees about how long it takes to execute the code running on the processor.

You have already done some research on Wikipedia; some of the keywords above should help track down more articles on the subject, and from there you should be able to find plenty of primary sources to learn more on the subject.

Comment: In the case there is no minimum number of instruction, if two thread call pthread_lock() how it is guaranteed that a particular thread locks successfully before the other. How even this mechanism works?

Comment: There are processor instructions that are "atomic" like TSL (test-set-lock). These instructions perform a comparison and store a result within a single instruction, and are used to implement locks by the operating system. For your example, the two threads each attempt to acquire the lock, and as part of that operation use a TSL instruction. The first thread that has the TSL instruction successfully execute acquires the lock; the second thread to execute the instruction will fail and go into a wait state on the lock.

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX threads, there are two main scheduling policies (FIFO and Round Robin). Round Robin is the default scheduler as it's more fair.

When RR scheduler is used, each thread has an amount of time (AKA quantum) to run, so there's no guarantee that an X number of instructions will get executed - unless we knew how much time each instruction takes.

You can find more about scheduling algorithms on PThreads here: http://maxim.int.ru/bookshelf/PthreadsProgram/htm/r_37.html

Just to give an idea on how Linux defines the round round quantum:

```
/*
 * default timeslice is 100 msecs (used only for SCHED_RR tasks).
 * Timeslices get refilled after they expire.
 */
#define RR_TIMESLICE        (100 * HZ / 1000)

#endif /* _LINUX_SCHED_RT_H */
```